# CSS to Affect Specific Level of "li"

Tags: css

i have a css class called `sidebar_menu` it affects a menu on the sidebar (duh) that sometimes has nested submenus

for example, lets say i have this:

- Delaware
- Ohio

  - Cleveland
  - Columbus
- Texas

i am trying to only affect the first level of the list, so i have been trying things like the direct child selector, but to no avail. if i have the code

`div.sidebar_menu ul.menu > li {font-weight: bold;}`

i am looking for

- **Delaware**
- **Ohio**

  - Cleveland
  - Columbus
- **Texas**

instead, i get every item in the submenus boldfaced as well, which i dont want. any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Set a style for the child items separately. They're inheriting the parent's style so you need to override it.

Comment: @j08691 do mean add something like "div.sidebar_menu ul.menu li ul.menu > li"?

that will automatically override what happened above it?

Comment: You'd have to post the HTML and CSS for me to know whether that should work or not. A jsFiddle would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about it the other way around. You can apply the bold weight to all `li`s, and then apply a normal weight to the nested `li`s.

```
.sidebar_menu li {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.sidebar_menu li li {
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

Obviously change the selectors to what you need to select the `li` and `li li` pieces.